# Pair of jlists with the same model (How to remove from one the selected of other)

Tags: java, jlist, mouselistener

I have a model with some string values.This model, I apply it to two jlists. I need every time that I click from one jlist a value, that value to dissapear from the other. Then the same if it happents to the other jlist but first the values must be updated to those the model contains. I made some effort but with my code when I click one value then it dissapears on both lists!
What am I doing wrong?
Here is the code:

```
 /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
*/

package accessfiletest;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.*;


/**
 *
* @author 
*/

 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MoveFolders extends JFrame  
{
//start of class MoveFolders 
//start of variables
private DefaultListModel<String> theModel;
private DefaultListModel<String> fromModel;
private DefaultListModel<String> toModel;
private JList<String> fromJList;
private JList<String> toList;
private JButton moveButton;
private JPanel theJPanel;
//end of variables
public MoveFolders( DefaultListModel<String> model1)
{
 super("Μετακίνηση Εγγράφων από Φάκελο σε Φάκελο");
 fromModel=model1;
 toModel=model1;
 theModel=model1;
 theJPanel=new JPanel(null);
 fromJList=new JList<>(fromModel);
 fromJList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
 fromJList.setSelectedIndex(0);
 fromJList.addMouseListener(fromlistener);

JScrollPane frompane=new  JScrollPane(fromJList);
frompane.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 150);
theJPanel.add(frompane);
moveButton=new JButton("ΜΕΤΑΚΙΝΗΣΗ >>");
moveButton.setBounds(260, 90, 150, 20);
theJPanel.add(moveButton);
toList=new JList<>(toModel);
 if (model1.getSize()>1)
   {
    toList.setSelectedIndex(1);

   }
else
   {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
"Πρέπει να έχετε πάνω από 1 φάκελο για να γίνει αντιγραφή εγγράφων.\nΤο παράθυρο θα       κλείσει.", "Λάθος", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
 dispose();
   }
 toList.addMouseListener(toListener);
 toList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
 JScrollPane topane=new  JScrollPane(toList);
 topane.setBounds(420, 50, 200, 150);
 theJPanel.add(topane);

 add(theJPanel);
 setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
 setSize(670, 300);
 setVisible(true);
 }

 MouseListener fromlistener = new MouseAdapter() {
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
        final int index = fromJList.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                   toModel=theModel;
                   toModel.remove(index);
                }
            });
        }
   }
};

MouseListener toListener = new MouseAdapter() {
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
        final int index = fromJList.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    fromModel=theModel;
                    fromModel.remove(index);
                }
            });
     }
   }

  };

}//end of class MoveFolders
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each list need use its own reference of `ListModel`,

```
    public MoveFolders(DefaultListModel<String> model1) {
        ...
        fromModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        for (Object obj : model1.toArray()) {
            fromModel.addElement((String) obj);
        }
        toModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        theModel = model1;
        ...
    }
```

For move elements `fromModel` to `toModel`

```
    MouseListener fromlistener = new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                final int index = fromJList.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int index = fromJList.getSelectedIndex();
                        toModel.addElement(fromModel.getElementAt(index));
                        fromModel.remove(index);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
```

For move elements `toModel` to `fromModel`

```
    MouseListener toListener = new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                final int index = fromJList.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int index = toList.getSelectedIndex();
                        fromModel.addElement(toModel.getElementAt(index));
                        toModel.remove(index);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    };


}
```

I hope that this can help you

Comment: Thank you for your efford. But I am new java user and I dont feel comfortable just copy paste some code that I do not fully understand. Is there any way to fix my code with minor changes based on my way of thinging?

Answer (score 1):

You are using twice the same model but they are actually different. Use different models if they are intrinsically different. It is only normal that if you modify a model used by different views (the JList) they both reflect the changes on the underlying model.

Comment: I need to have the same model for both. But actually here I use 2 different with the same values.Or not?

Comment: No, you have different fields that all reference the same model.

Comment: so you say that toModel and fromModel are the same? So when I remove one value from one dissapear from the other?

Comment: @Vagelism Precisely. What you could do is pass a List of String to your constructor and then instantiate 2 different DefaultListModel and add all elements of the same List.

Comment: What I have available is the model. Is there any way to take the lists from the model and then do the trick you mentioned above? I dont know if there is a method to pass the values of the model to a List.